# Splitting audio in julia

Tags: audio, split, stream, load, julia

I want to make some operations with an mp3 file or WAV file, like splitting, but idk how to make it in Julia, i saw that the pkgs LibSndFile.jl, AudioIO.jl and WAV.jl don't work well, is there any library that will help me with that issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "splitting" reading the file and saving it in chunks? Or perhaps source separation?
WAV.jl works just fine though.